# Azure Devops Pipeline Scheduled trigger on other repository

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a repo with Yaml definition of pipelines, that reference other repo for steps.

I'm trying to have the pipeline triggered based on a scheduled (cron) definition (only when source code changed) of a repo that is not the repo of the pipeline.
I tried that but the pipeline is not triggered:

```
resources:
 repositories:
 - repository: self
   type: git
   ref: master
 - repository: my-project
   name: my-project
   type: git
   ref: master
   schedules:
   - cron: 55 10 * * 1,2,3,4,5
     branches:
     include:
     - master
     always: false
     
trigger: none
pr: none
(...)
```

Repository "self" references the repo with pipeline YAML file(s)

If I get rid of the last two lines, the pipeline is triggered when I save it, but not when I change code on "`my-project`"
I tried also with `ref/heads` prefixes for branch name without any change.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't be done, the way you're trying. A repository resource can include a trigger, but not a schedule; see the docs at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#define-a-repositories-resource

What you *can* do is a non-scheduled trigger:

```
resources:
 repositories:
 - repository: self
   type: git
   ref: master
 - repository: my-project
   name: my-project
   type: git
   ref: master
   trigger:
     branches:
       include:
       - master
```

This won't work on any schedule; it will simply be immediately triggered by any change to the code in my-project, in the master branch.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I hoped there was a way to do it but as you mention this is not possible.